Преобразовать строчку, удалить пробелы
Есть строчка:
const txt = '    #text # textx   saad #asadsas   '

Как лучше всего выполнить 3 операции

удалить пробелы в начале строки
Удалить все пробелы что после символа #
Заменить все пробелы, что равно и более 2, на одинарные пробелы





задача
то есть ...




удалить пробелы в начале строки
... удалить все пробелы после начала строки


Удалить все пробелы что после символа #
... удалить все пробелы после решётки


Заменить все пробелы, что равно и более 2, на одинарные пробелы
... удалить все пробелы после пробела



Все три задачи сведены к общей форме, которая решается так:
// символы после которых нужно удалять пробелы в группе
//              |
//              |   повторить много раз
//              |        |
//              v        v
//           --------    -
txt.replace(/(^|\s|#)\s+/g, '$1')
//                   ---     --
//                    ^      ^
//                    |      |
//                    |   оставить только группу в круглых скобках
//                    |
//        пробелы, которые будут удалены


$ node
Welcome to Node.js v18.19.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const txt = '    #text # textx   saad #asadsas   ';
undefined
> txt.replace(/(^|\s|#)\s*/g, '$1')
'#text #textx saad #asadsas '



Возможно заменить повторяющиеся подряд # на один символ, в данной же операции. Не добавляя еще одну replace


Как лучше всего выполнить 3 операции

Предложу такой вариант...
Добавил еще замену нескольких # подряд на одну #.


const s = '    #text # textx   ###test1    ###  test2   saad #asadsas   '
const r = /(?<=^|#)\s+|(\s+|#+)(?=\1)/g
console.log('"%s"', s.replace(r, ''))




Здорово. replace(/\#{2,}/g, ' #') Заменяю 2 и более символа # на один и также смотрю на первый символ путем (str[0] != '#' ? '#' : '') +str;.  Возможно 2 данные задачи, объединить в одну, через выражение?

@Лена, к тем 3 пунктам добавить еще замену нескольких "решеток" подряд на одну?

/(?<=^|#)\s+|(\s+|#+)(?=\1)/g, в примере работает, у меня не хочет, я пишу в html документе, возможно из-за этого. Но если прописать так /((?<=^|#)\s+|(\s+|#+)){2,}/g, работает но не так как хотелось. Есть ли выход в моем случаи, когда джаваскрипт необходимо прописать в самом в html документе. Вероятно в это дело...

@Лена, JS он и в Африке JS. Не важно где запускать мой пример. :)  Возможно твоя "строка" не такая как в твоем вопросе, от того и результат работы разнится. Т.е. от тебя нужен некий пример того, с чем ты имеешь дело на практике...



console.log('"' + ('   #text # textx   saad #asadsas   '.replace(/(\s+){2,}/g, ' ').replace(/^(\s+)/, '').replace(/#(\s+)/, '#')) + '"');



Результат
"#text #textx saad #asadsas "


Супер, replace(/(\s+){2,}/g, ' ').  Возможно улучшить выражение для тех случаев, когда необходимо добавить пробел перед # если его нет и это не первый символ в строчке.

Боюсь моих знаний регулярных выражений хватит только на вот такой грязный трюк console.log('"'+s.replace(/^#/, '@').replace(/(\s+){0}#/g, ' #').replace(/^@/, '#')+'"');

Конкретно для указанной строки:
const str = "  #text # textx   saad #asadsas   "
const result1 = str.trim(' ')
const result2 = str.replace('# ', '#')
const result3 = str.replace('  ', ' ')


Ни один из пунктов не выполнен: 1) Удаляет также символы в конце строки 2) Удаляет только один пробел после # 3) Заменяет только пару пробелов одним пробелом. Также каждая операция в данном решении применяется к исходной строке по отдельности.
